# TextView Overlapping in one of the GridView columns

Tags: java, android, sqlite, gridview, textview

I'm filling the Gridview with Textview values which are retrieved from the local SQLite database. Basically what I've implemented is that the movie items are pushed into the database once they are marked as favorite.

But the textviews are overlapping with each other if the content does not fit in one line.

[image: Overlapped Textviews]

However, what's more strange is, if the long content (which requires 2 or more lines) is there on the right hand side (i.e. these are in even rows of the database table) they work fine!

[image]

My Gridview is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.p1.MainActivity$MostPopular">

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/griview_toprated"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit">

</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And Textview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/checkTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I've searched a lot, played with the item height, width to match parent, wrap content but couldn't find any solution!

Comment: try changing  android:numColumns="auto_fit" to  android:numColumns="2"

Comment: Tried that earlier, didn't work.

Comment: gridview cant handle left and right item with uneven size , restrict the textview to max 3 or 4 lines

Comment: try adding `android:inputType="textMultiLine"` to textview

Comment: @AnupDasari Doesn't work! It shows warning that the inputType should not be used with <TextView> Change element type to <EditText>. It isn't supposed to be Edit text btw!

Comment: @ankitagrawal If it can't handle uneven size then how is it working fine if the long text is in the second column?

Comment: becoz it matches the size with the right column and not the left column

Comment: u can use recyclerview with staggeredGridLayoutManager which is made for handling this case

Comment: Could you please elaborate on above point -  "matches the size with the right column and not the left column". And using the property `android:maxLine = "5"` didn't work either.

Comment: android:maxLine = "5"  should work what happen when u give max lines ==5

Comment: @ankitagrawal even after setting the maxLines attribute the output is still the same.

Comment: @T.M can you find any solution , i am facing same problem